# How do you configure cvs2git to handle multiple CVS directories?

Tags: git, cvs2git

This question is related to my recent git [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042882/determining-how-cvs2git-converted-cvs-trees).

Other than writing a shell script, I'm not quite sure how to configure cv2git to have it read a Linux directory SRC_TREE in which are multiple CVS projects. Any pointers would be appreciated.

I am providing my recent post to show work towards this effort. I'm not asking without having first tried.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support in cvs2git for converting multiple projects from CVS to git in one run of the program.  So there is no alternative to running cvs2git once per repository.  Writing a shell script is probably the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Thats very easy. Just use SRC_TREE/module instead of just SRC_TREE as your module root (first parameter of `run_options.set_project()` in an options file or simply on command line.

If you want to have the module name as root path in your git tree, use SRC_TREE directly but ignore all modules which you don't want.

If your plans are more advanced, I recommend to make a copy of your cvs directory (if you didn't already do) and move around your directories however you like it (join or split modules) before starting tha conversion.